# PHP nested Entity

Tags: php, model-view-controller, entity

Hi I'm wondering what is best practice for creating entity in below case
Table
customer

- customer_id
- customer_name
- customer_family_name
- customer_creation_date

customer_contact ( this to provide unlimited contact list for a customer )

- customer_id
- customer_contact_type ( i.e email, telephone, bb )
- customer_contact_value

customer_info

- customer_id
- customer_info_type ( all info that not related to customer personal info, for system use )
- customer_info_value

With above table should I create entity for each table ?
Sometime e.g customer_info will have no meaning without joining other table, it useless when it is on their own.

If we want to have a meaningful entity we create it like below

CustomerEntity

- customer_id int
- customer_name string
- customer_info array -----> this one will be collection
- customer_contact --------> this one will also be a collection

But this will make an entity a bit complex no ? should I allow a collection inside an entity ? or this is a job for Mapper or maybe Factory ?

-OR-

We create entity for each table then let the entity nested other entity ? Is it a good practice

-OR-

We do cartesian for each table so each row is an entity ?